# choose ODF vs OOXML

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice

I just found out about the "war" between ODF and OOXML and I was wondering which was "winning" and whether I should support one over the other in an project that I am about to start up soon.  I have a bias toward The Document Foundation as I used to contribute to LibreOffice, but that does not mean that choosing them is the best business decision.

Does it matter? Should I support one? both?choose ODF vs OOXML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious choice is ODF, both for technical interoperability and moral principle.

The OOXML format was created by Microsoft and, according to [this blog](http://ooxmlisdefectivebydesign.blogspot.ca), is flawed by design.

Although it's a question with many subjective aspects, Microsoft is known for conducting dubious actions regarding the voting process on normative commitees and taking abusive advantage of their dominant place in the software industry.

[This thread](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/07/12/17/2340242/microsofts-influence-on-upcoming-iso-vote) on slashdot gives interesting insight on how the ISO standard is being debated in the IT world.

Comment: I was not aware that Microsoft made OOXML. Thanks. As I said I had a LibreOffice bias.  In that case I think it is my moral obligation to choose ODF.